# Web request unable to enter Server

Tags: linux, tomcat, aix, apache-1.3

I have a website hosted on AIX server on Tomcat.

It receives its requests from another server with Apche installed on it and the server with Apache on it sets on request header as well.

Recently I upgraded the OS and some hardware on the hosting server and since then the other server where Apache is installed is unable to send any requests.

But the site is up on my end of the server.

I'm getting the error

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.

The proxy server could not handle the request GET/student_itr/index.html

Reason : Could not connect to the remote machine : Connection timed out

Apache/1.3.34 Server at test.forwarder.com Port 443
```

I think some thing might be blocking this upstream request from entering this server. How can I check the same.

What can be the probable causes for the same.

Comment: Can you telnet from the apache server to tomcat server (to the tomcat port)??

Comment: @Schrute : Telnet is not working from apache server to tomcat server to the tomcat port 8080.

Comment: Check firewall then.  If firewall allows connection the telnet will respond.

Comment: How do I check the firewall if this is getting blocked.

Comment: There are many different firewalls so not sure in your case.

Comment: I checked the telnet from another server, it says it connected to the the server and after a few seconds it says `Connection closed by foreign host`. Is this normal response. Is it suppose to close the connection on its own.

Comment: If you key GET you should see a HTTP response if this is listening on HTTP, not sure about AJP I've not had a recent example to recall.

Comment: I typed `GET/ HTTP/1.0` I got no response and I got the message Connection closed by foreign host. What can this mean.

Comment: AIX... apache1... broargh!

Comment: No comment on the Apache version :)